# hovering elements over the links in an arbitrary HTML

Tags: html

I have an arbitrary HTML I am outputting to a page inside of a table, and I need to be able to "layer" elements over all of the links (one per link).

My current solution is to search the HTML for the links (which I have in a separate array from another source), then insert a div with a different z-index and position absolute into the HTML. This works some of the time, and breaks bizarrely other times.

Is there something that I'm missing here? I've seen nice implementations of this on various forums, but they are slightly different in that they usually require interaction from the user to come up, I want mine to be up all of the time.

Long question short, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript (and specifically jQuery), yes.

There are many tooltip libraries out there.

- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tooltips
- http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html
- http://craigsworks.com/projects/simpletip/

I'd say the top one would suit your needs the best. To enable it to be "always on" you'd set the css element `.tooltip` as follows:

```
.tooltip {
    display:block; // This replaces the "none" they have in the example, but the line itself isn't necessary
    font-size:12px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#fff; 
}
```

Comment: interesting, but I need "always on" tooltips, is that possible with any of these? Also, how much of a pain is jQuery to set up? I've never used it before. I should mention that this project is in vanilla ASP (ugh)

Comment: It's not a pain at all to set up. Incredibly easy. One line of code and you've got it installed. And yeah, it's possible to have them always on. Typically, you'll set up a hover event listener that will turn them "on" but if you wanted them always up you'd just toggle it there.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind to see if you get getter results.  1) have you tried relative positioning inside the table cells instead of absolute positioning?  2) is your script firing after the table is rendered?  If not, be sure it runs after the entire table is rendered.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of different CSS, the hovering doesnt seem to be the problem, its the positioning thats a bit wonky. I have the HTML in a variable before outputting it, so I am scanning through it at that time and inserting divs before the links. Is there a better way to position divs using javascript? I found this http://www.wohill.com/a-drag-box-or-a-floating-div/ page, and it seems that I could modify that to do what I want, its just that I need to set the starting position of the divs somehow.

Comment: You don't know the starting position (x,y coordinates) until the cells are actually rendered in the browser.  That's why I mentioned trying relative positioning.  If you table isn't too big and you don't care about performance, you may be able to get away with calling your function on each TD render, but that is really risky if the table is huge and not ideal.  The other option is start over looking at a jQuery plugin which usually handles issues like this.  I was born in the world of roll your own javascript, css and dhtml though, so I always try to solve manually first :)